# Wordpress: Return to last page after Facebook login

Tags: php, wordpress, facebook-login, redirect

I am using `WOW Facebook Login` Plugin. When I am on login page and login as Facebook then after login it goes to home page successfully.

Now there is a page `foo` in this page I want that when a user click on "Login with Facebook" and after login its redirect on same page `foo`. I search a lot about this but nothing get.

Its a plugin so i have no code except short-code `[Wow-Facebook-Login]`.
So please guide me is there any other way for this issue.

Comment: Please provide the code, which you have tried it so far. We don't just code for you

Comment: If you give me the url I can have a look